# In a regression model fitting, should we should check for the normality of the response at each level of X, but not collectively for X?

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

My questions stems from this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/390839/37540

I understand that we should check normality of residuals.

But regarding dependent variable, am I understand correctly all below for linear regression?

1. We should check normality of dependent variable for each level of independent variable.
2. We should not check normality for whole dependent variable.

Comment: That is correct.  The assumption is that the conditonal distribution of the outcome (conditioned on the variables) is normal.  The marginal distribution could, for instance, be bimodal and we could still use linear regression.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Is the "check normality of dependent variable for each level of independent variable" same as checking normality of residuals or it is different?

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent.

Comment: @DemetriPananos This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Strictly any assumptions are about the unknown errors or disturbances. In practice that can only be checked by looking at residuals, as by definition you don't know the errors.

Comment: Actually, no, checking normality of residuals is not equivalent to checking normality of $Y$ at each level of $X$. You can have a normal error distribution when the conditionals are non-normal. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/102879